# ValueError: Cannot assign "<Classname: V>": "Teachername.classname" must be a "Sectionname" instance

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-views

My models.py:

```
class Classname(models.Model):  

    class_name = models.CharField(max_length=8) 

    def __str__(self):  
        return self.class_name  

class Sectionname(models.Model):  

    class_name = models.ForeignKey(Classname)  
    section_name = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='A')  
    def __str__(self):  
        return self.section_name  

class Teachername(models.Model):  
    classname = models.ForeignKey(Sectionname)
    secname = models.ForeignKey(Classname)  
    teachname = models.CharField(max_length=50)  
    def __str__(self):  
        return self.teachname
```

my views.py:

```
def add_teach(request):  
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        form = TeachernameForm(request.POST)  
         if form.is_valid():  
            form.save()  
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('student:listteach'))  
        else:  
            print(form.errors)  
    else:  
        form = TeachernameForm()  
    return render(request, 'add_teach.html', {'form': form},)
```

my form.py:

```
class TeachernameForm(ModelForm):  
    classname = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Classname.objects.all())  
    secname = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Sectionname.objects.all())  
    class Meta:  
        model = Teachername  
        fields = ('classname', 'secname', 'teachname',)
```

When I'm submitting the TeacherForm. I got the above error. I try many tricks but didn't get the solution. Please some one suggest me the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Teachername(models.Model):  
    classname = models.ForeignKey(Sectionname)
    secname = models.ForeignKey(Classname)
```

This should probably be:

```
    classname = models.ForeignKey(Classname)
    secname = models.ForeignKey(Sectionname)
```